# 'tflite_convert' is not recognized as an internal or external command (in windows)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, converters, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

im trying to convert my saved_model.pb(from object detection API) file to .tflite for mlkit but when i execute the command on cmd:

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=/saved_model/maonani.tflite \
  --saved_model_dir=/saved_model/saved_model
```

i get a response saying

```
C:\Users\LENOVO-PC\tensorflow> tflite_convert \ --output_file=/saved_model/maonani.tflite \ --saved_model_dir=/saved_model/saved_model
'tflite_convert' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

what should i do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Below is answer for Linux system, hope it gives you ideas for Windows.

1. locate tflite_convert
    if output is 
     /tflite_convert 
    where TFLITE_CONVERT_PATH depends on your TF installation, execute (2)

   2. /tflite_convert \
      --output_file=/saved_model/maonani.tflite \   --saved_model_dir=/saved_model/saved_model

      if output is not found, reinstall tf, in my case it is tf v1.9
   3. if (2) works, you might add PATH=$PATH:/bin in ~/.bashrc
   4. if "locate" command not recognized, install it by 
      sudo apt-get install locate

Comment: did you mean like this? `C:\Users\LENOVO-PC\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\lite\python> tflite_convert \ --output_file=/saved_model/maonani.tflite \ --saved_model_dir=/saved_model/saved_model`   @user10046237